# Jquery form validation

Tags: jquery, html, validation

I am having issues merging my currently; page separated input validation onto a single webpage. 
Here is my attempt but it wont call both of the functions, any idea why

Jquery:

```
    <script>
function isValidPassword(Passwordreg){
    var pattern = new RegExp(/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z]{8,}$/);
    return pattern.test(Passwordreg);
};
function isValidEmailAddress(emailAddress) {
    var pattern = new RegExp(/^[+a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/i);
    return pattern.test(emailAddress);
};
    $( document ).ready(function(){
        $("#email" ).focus();
        $( "#email" ).blur(function() {
        checkEmail($("#email").val());
        });
        $( "#email" ).keydown(function() {
            checkEmail($("#email").val());
        $( "#Password" ).blur(function() {
            checkPassword($("#Password").val());
        });
        $( "#Password" ).keydown(function() {
            checkPassword($("#Password").val());
    });

function checkPassword(Pword){
    if(!isValidPassword($("#Password" ).val())){
        $( "#passwordError" ).html("Does Not Match the Reqirements");
        $("#emailError" ).addClass("error");
        $('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
        return false;
    }else{
        $( "#passwordError" ).html("");
        $("#Password" ).removeClass("error");
        $('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', false);
        return true;
    }

}
function checkEmail(emailAddie){
    if(!isValidEmailAddress($("#email" ).val())){
        $( "#emailError" ).html("Please inert a correctly layed out email address");
        $("#email" ).addClass("error");
        $('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
        return false;
    }else{
        $( "#emailError" ).html("");
        $("#email" ).removeClass("error");
        $('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', false);
        return true;
    }

}
$("#submitB").click(function(e) {
        if(!checkPassword($("#Password").val())){
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

And my form has 6 inputs on it but we only need to focus on the 2

```
<form>
      <label for="email">Username / Email address</label>
        <input id="email" type="text" name="email" ><span id="emailError"></span>
      <label for="Password">Password</label>
        <input id="Password" type="password" name="Password" ><span id="passwordError"></span>
</form>
```

Again these functions work if i try to call them separately with the triggers I have set-up, but they fail when I try to monitor both inputs at once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error n your code. So it is not working for you.

Here is the fixed code.

```js
function isValidPassword(Passwordreg){
    var pattern = new RegExp(/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z]{8,}$/);
    return pattern.test(Passwordreg);
};
function isValidEmailAddress(emailAddress) {
    var pattern = new RegExp(/^[+a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/i);
    return pattern.test(emailAddress);
};
    $( document ).ready(function(){
        $("#email" ).focus();
        $( "#email" ).blur(function() {
        checkEmail($("#email").val());
        });
        $( "#email" ).keydown(function() {
            checkEmail($("#email").val());
        $( "#Password" ).blur(function() {
            checkPassword($("#Password").val());
        });
        $( "#Password" ).keydown(function() {
            checkPassword($("#Password").val());
      });
        });

function checkPassword(Pword){
    if(!isValidPassword($("#Password" ).val())){
        $( "#passwordError" ).html("Does Not Match the Reqirements");
        $("#emailError" ).addClass("error");
        $('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
        return false;
    }else{
        $( "#passwordError" ).html("");
        $("#Password" ).removeClass("error");
        $('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', false);
        return true;
    }

}
function checkEmail(emailAddie){
    if(!isValidEmailAddress($("#email" ).val())){
        $( "#emailError" ).html("Please inert a correctly layed out email address");
        $("#email" ).addClass("error");
        $('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
        return false;
    }else{
        $( "#emailError" ).html("");
        $("#email" ).removeClass("error");
        $('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', false);
        return true;
    }

}
$("#submitB").click(function(e) {
        if(!checkPassword($("#Password").val())){
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="jquery" data-semver="3.0.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form>
      <label for="email">Username / Email address</label>
        <input id="email" type="text" name="email" ><span id="emailError"></span>
      <label for="Password">Password</label>
        <input id="Password" type="password" name="Password" ><span id="passwordError"></span>
</form>
    <!-- Put your html here! -->
  </body>

</html>
```

[Here is a plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/fSbsFcqMwAx24kXGv2QX?p=preview)

Comment: Oh wow just 3 characters and i would be on my way, thank you so much, you have saved me so much struggle

Comment: yeah one charecter some times spoils our day. Have a good day. :-)